# Catch in Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

In following code, I am trying to catch an error associated with invalid link. However instead of an error, I receive following warning and an error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://aaajsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
>
> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.[Learn More]

Here is the code

```
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'; // This URL is valid

    async function getPostData(){
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();

        return data;
    }


    document
    .getElementById('btnGET')
    .addEventListener('click',
    () => {
        getPostData()
        .then( data => console.log(data))
        .catch( () => {throw new Error('Woops! Something went wrong')});
    });
```

Based on my understanding, following is what happens inside `getPostData`

[1] a HTTP GET request is issued via Fetch API to previously defined URL;
[2] the data variable is initialized with the response, that is either resolve or reject;
[3] the Promise is returned;

In the event the URL is invalid, I would expect the code in the `EventListener` to trigger `cache` but it does not happen. What did I do wrong?

Comment: FWIW, 3 happens before 2.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense since `response.json()` returns the actual data after it has been executed. Hence, it is no longer a `Promise` but an `Array`. The `data` on return is still wrapped into a `Promise` though, no?

Comment: The fetch function [can throw an exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch). In fact, it can throw _two_ different exceptions.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JZmQOw?editors=1010

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans does it mean chained `catch` would NOT be triggered? I was under impression `catch` would trigger in this situation.

Comment: @NagaSaiA the issue remains if you make the `URL` invalid

Comment: The trick is to verify your exceptions in question: the TypeError would be caught if you try/catch the `fetch`, but the CORS violation is a network level error, and cannot be "caught"

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I appreciate your input on this matter. I am still relatively new to JS; trying to wrap my mind around Fetch API, Promises, and now async and await. I will close this question now by accepting the answer below

Comment: The only thing I see wrong with your code is the `throw new Error(...)` in your `.catch()` handler.  That creates an uncaught promise rejection.  There's no need to throw there because there's nobody listening for it.  Just "handle" the error there however you want (show an error message or something like that).  Other than that, your code appears to work properly.  Don't really know what the question is.  You cannot suppress everything that the browser might decide to put in the console.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have figured this out, given the answer below. As you said, I just "handle" in `catch`. Now, I want to figure out how did I end up with a Cross Origin Request but that's a different matter. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @JaromandaX I appreciate the sarcasm. I know what Cross Origin Request is, what I do not understand is why it was blocked. Given the URL is valid, the requests resolve with 2xx response code. If URL is invalid, I would expect the HTTP response to come with 4xx response code.

Comment: Curiously enough when I paste your code into [a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/uf6gxwac/) and look in the console, it runs just fine without any cross origin errors.  So, not sure where you are getting that.  Apparently, the `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` server is allowing cross origin requests.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's my point. I know it works fine when the URL is valid, the request is blocked when the URL is invalid. I would expect the HTTP to respond with 4xx instead but it doesn't

Comment: can you show an invalid URL that demonstrates your issue? because even a 404 on that site, i.e. `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/garbage` doesn't get "blocked"

Comment: oh I see now ... you're using an invalid HOST - well, `https://aaaajsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` doesn't send CORS allow headers, so of course your CORS request is blocked

Comment: It doesn't make sense to check for CORS related HTTP headers, given HTTP response is 4xx. The question is closed though, so thank you all for your replies.

Comment: You may be a little confused about the type of error you get for different situations.  A bad domain (e.g. a server that does not response or fails DNS lookup) should reject the promise from `fetch()` with some network error (not a 404 response status).  A 404 is ONLY for when the client gets a connection to an HTTP server, but the server responds with a 404 error that it doesn't know that path.  So, a bad host, port or protocol will likely reject the promise.  A bad path sent to an otherwise functioning http server will likely generate a 404 error.

Comment: Remember, a 404 only occurs when a SUCCESSFUL connection is made to an HTTP server and the HTTP server responds with a 404 status.  When a request is blocked by the browser because of CORS or a bad or unresponsive host, that is not considered a 404.  It rejects the `fetch()` call with some other error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `getPostData()` should `throw` an error in case something goes wrong, then `catch` it in the callback of the `click` event :

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'; // This URL is valid

async function getPostData(){
  try{
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
  }
  catch(e){
    throw new Error('Woops! Something went wrong' + e)}
  }
}


document
.getElementById('btnGET')
.addEventListener('click',
() => {
    getPostData()
    .then( data => console.log(data))
    .catch( (err) => { console.log(err)});
});
```

Comment: In other words, the `catch` attached to the `Promise` chain will `cache` only those `Error` messages which are explicitly declared via `try-catch` block as above? Otherwise, the chained `catch` block ignores the errors?

Comment: no it will `catch` all the other errors, but the idea here is not to `re-throw` the error in the `.catch()` but rather throw it in the `async` function

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. I will upvote and accept it. Perhaps you could explain why I get `CORS` warning, if you know about it. I would appreciate that.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this code.  You don't have to wrap an async function internals with try/catch.  The JS interpreter already does that for you with an `async` function and if an exception is thrown or an `await` promise is rejected, the promise that the async function returns will just be rejected.  This is the other main advantage of an `async` function (aside from being able to use `await`).  So, one does not need their own try/catch here if you just want the error to go back to the caller as a rejected promise.  So, I don't see what this solves.

Comment: @jfriend00 - that's an interesting comment. Most async/await "tutorials" I've seen suggests you *should* wrap the internals in try/catch!! I'm not suggesting you are wrong by the way

Comment: @JaromandaX - If you want any rejection to just abort further processing and reject back to the caller, adding a try/catch and then just rethrowing the same exception is just wasted code.  No need as the `async` function infrastructure does that for you.  But, the more common mistake is if you don't have a try/catch inside the `async` function, then the caller must catch any rejections which the OP is doing here with a `.catch()`.

Comment: Ahh, of course, to handle the exception in some way inside an async function you would use try/catch - I'll have to go back to those tutorials, see if they are doing that :p

Comment: @jfriend00 the main thing i wanted is to use the `error` thrown by the `async` function in the `.catch()` like `.catch( (err) => console.log(err));` instead of `.catch( () => {throw new Error('Woops! Something went wrong')});` , as for the internal `try/catch` , i guess i was following what i've seen in tutorials and [example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) like @JaromandaX mentionned, good to know they are needless.

Comment: @e.doroskevic for the `CORS` warning i'm not sure but iguess it's in the warning : `Reason: CORS request did not succeed`